# running ipython in non-interactive mode

Tags: ipython, non-interactive

I was hoping it would be easy to rewrite a few bash scripts using ipython by using the "!" command.  Unfortunately if I try to run ipython in non-interactive mode like so:

```
ipython -p sh myipythonscript.py
```

where myipythonscript.py contains commands like:

```
env=%env
d=!ls
```

This doesn't work.  I get SyntaxError.
Is there an option which allows ipython to be run in non-interactive mode?

Comment: rename your file with the .ipy extensions and it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Python also has modules which makes it easy to completely replace bash calls. these are easier to debug and give better error handling.

for example instead of `ls` you can use `glob`, it supports the same syntax:

```
files=glob.glob('myfiles*.txt')
```

for environment variables:

```
env = os.environ
```

for path related functions:

```
os.path
```

for common operations, `os.mkdir`, `os.chmod`, `os.getcwd` [same as pwd]